# Solaris Related Query... Related to dns server

Tags: solaris

Hi I am new to Solaris World.... I am working out on a Solaris Server, which is booting up, but due to some internal settings failure,, i am not able to run my project over it.....

I check /var/adm/messages file.... And noted two things..... The date is incorrect and dns name server resolution problem......

I am in process of chaning the date with following command "date -u 062800002010", but the system date is not being changing.....

And how to go about this dns file.... i guess it is somewhere /etc.... Please help me on these two issues....

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The DNS servers are set in /etc/resolv.conf like on linux, however you may have to edit the NSS configuration to use DNS. Check the hosts line in /etc/nsswitch.conf reads something like:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate about changing the date not working for you ?